# R regularize coefficients in regression

Tags: r, regression

I'm trying to use linear regression to figure out the best weighting for 3 models to predict an outcome.  So there are 3 variables `(x1, x2, x3)` that are the predictions of the dependent variable, `y`.  My question is, how do I run a regression with the constraint that the sum of the coefficients sum to 1.  For example:

this is good:

```
y = .2(x1) + .4(x2) + .4(x3)
```

since `.2 + .4 + .4 = 1`

this is no good:

```
y = 1.2(x1) + .4(x2) + .3(x3)
```

since `1.2 + .4 + .3 > 1`

I'm looking to do this in R if possible.  Thanks.  Let me know if this needs to get moved to the stats area ('Cross-Validated').

EDIT:

The problem is to classify each row as 1 or 0.  y is the actual values ( 0 or 1 ) from the training set, x1 is the predicted values from a kNN model, x2 is from a randomForest, x3 is from a gbm model.  I'm trying to get the best weightings for each model, so each coefficient is <=1 and the sum of the coefficients == 1.
Would look something like this:

```
y/Actual value       knnPred      RfPred     gbmPred
      0                .1111       .0546       .03325
      1                .7778       .6245       .60985
      0                .3354       .1293       .33255
      0                .2235       .9987       .10393
      1                .9888       .6753       .88933
     ...                 ...         ...         ...
```

The measure for success is AUC.  So I'm trying to set the coefficients to maximize AUC while making sure they sum to 1.

Comment: Try: http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/3143/229

Comment: Here's what you do: construct a small example, list the packages you are using and the code to create the output you are seeing and then someone will be in a position to offer advice.

Comment: The `mgcv` package provides a function `pcls()` (penalized constrained least squares fitting), which allows specification of linear equality _and_ inequality constraints for the parameters. You need to set up your models at a slightly lower level than, e.g. `lm()`, but the power it buys you is likely to be worth the extra trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No data to test on:

```
mod1 <- lm(y ~ 0+x1+x2+x3, data=dat)
mod2 <- lm(y/I(sum(coef(mod1))) ~ 0+x1+x2+x3, data=dat)
```

And now that I think about it some more, skip mod2,  just:

```
coef(mod1)/sum(coef(mod1))
```

Comment: That is cool Dwin, but maybe would be necessary to restrict the coefficients to be between 0 and 1 also. I think.

Comment: Depends on what problem is being solved, and that was never stated.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of pertinent details, I've made some updates above.

Answer (score 6):

There's very likely a better way that someone else will share, but you're looking for two parameters such that

```
b1 * x1 + b2 * x2 + (1 - b1 - b2) * x3
```

is close to `y`. To do that, I'd write an error function to minimize

```
minimizeMe <- function(b, x, y) {  ## Calculates MSE
    mean((b[1] * x[, 1] + b[2] * x[, 2] + (1 - sum(b)) * x[, 3] - y) ^ 2)
}
```

and throw it to `optim`

```
fit <- optim(par = c(.2, .4), fn = minimizeMe, x = cbind(x1, x2, x3), y = y)
```

Answer (score 0):

For the five rows shown either of `round(knnPred)` or `round(gbmPred)` give perfect predictions so there is some question whether more than one predictor is needed.

At any rate, to solve the given question as stated the following will give nonnegative coefficients that sum to 1 (except possibly for tiny differences due to computer arithmetic).  `a` is the dependent variable and `b` is a matrix of independent variables.  `c` and `d` define the equality constraint (coeffs sum to 1) and `e` and `f` define the inequality constraints (coeffs are nonnegative).

```
library(lsei)
a <- cbind(x1, x2, x3)
b <- y
c <- matrix(c(1, 1, 1), 1)
d <- 1
e <- diag(3)
f <- c(0, 0, 0)
lsei(a, b, c, d, e, f)
```